# “Default Activity Not Found” Android Studio 4.x

Tags: android, android-studio

After update to Android Studio 4.x
Build / run app shows "Default Activity Not Found".

Tried and not working:

- Invalidating cache
- Restarting
- cleanBuildCache
- ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Run** > **Edit Configuration**

In the general tab of your module make sure **Launch Options** > **Launch** is set to **Nothing**

Comment: added answer at the time of question creation itself :)

Comment: Indeed, this is a feature of StackOverflow. 
Couldn't find this solution easily so asked the question, answered the question, hopefully it saves people some time!

Comment: Hmm I see this used a lot, I'm wondering if this is a temporary work-around. It should be able to recognize it I have the name in my manifest and the intent filter set...